# Транскипция слова Delete. Какая именно?

Tags: грамматика, фонетика

Назрел вопрос про русское произношение слова "Delete". Загвоздка в том, что в британском английском это слово произносится как [di:'li:t] (Мюллер, Боянус)

В американском английском оно звучит как [dĕlit]. Сравнить на слух можно в Forvo - https://ru.forvo.com/word/delete/#en. Причём первый гласный в американском ближе к нашему Э "оборотному".

Последнее время складывается ситуация, когда полностью слово пишется как "Делит", а сокращённо -  то "Дэл", то "Дел". Хотя чаще предпочитают писать по английски. Но если требуется обязательно транскрибировать, то предпочитают форму "Дэл". Наверное, потому, что для русского языка, использование фонемы "э" - "Дэл", легче в произношении.

Правильно ли это? И как, на ваш слух, лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Есть сложившаяся система практической транскрипции с английского, в которой учитывается отчасти произношение, отчасти - исходное написание. После согласных и после "и" английское **e** передаётся как "**е**":

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Спасибо, но есть же ещё не установившиеся сочетания, которые должны будут пройти через отбор. В данном случае - имя рэпера Del, фигурирующего в составе группы "Gorillaz", трансрибирован как Дэл, И это уже устойчивая форма. А вот слово "rap" - до сих пор ещё часто пишут как "реп".